# django rest nested serializer object setting nested object in post method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

hi guys i hope you be healthy :)
okay i have an image model and a category model which have a foreignkey to image model like below:

image model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d")
alt = models.CharField(max_length=25)
name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=25, unique=True)
```

okay now i want to when i call a category get somting like this:

```
{
    "image":{
                "image":"https://example.com/media/image.png",
                "name":"image name",
                "alt":"image alternative"
            },
    "name":"category name",
    "slug":"category slug"
}
```

i write my serializer and views like below and getting a god json object like above
image serializer:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
image = serializers.ImageField()
alt = serializers.CharField(max_length=25)
name = serializers.CharField(max_length=25, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Image.objects.all(), message="there is another image with same name.")])
```

category serializer:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
image = ImageSerializer()
name = serializers.CharField(max_length=25,validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Category.objects.all()),])
slug = serializers.SlugField(max_length=25,validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Category.objects.all(),])

def validate_image(self, value):
    return get_object_or_404(Image, name=value['name'])
def create(self, validated_data):
    return Category.objects.create(**validated_data)
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
    instance.name = validated_data.get("name", instance.name)
    instance.slug = validated_data.get("slug", instane.slug)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

and here is category view:

```
class CategoriesView(APIView, PaginationMixin):
pagination_class = PageNumberPagination()
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
def get(self, request):
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    serializer = CategorySerializer(cats, many=True, context={"request":request})
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def post(self, request):
    serializer = CategorySerializer(data=request.data, partial=True, context={"request":request})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

now the problems is i cannot make any new category when i enter data below:

```
{
    "image":{
                "name":"an existing image name"
            },
    "name":"new category name",
    "slug":"new category slug"
}
```

i get this error:

```
    "image": {
    "name": [
        "there is another image with same name."
    ]
}
```

but it should get an existing image by its name by that code on category serializer image_validate but its runing image object self validation but im not trying to create an new image object i just want to get an image for a category, this thing is killing me alive! i searched every where its stopped me for two days i guess :(( some body help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem :))
in django rest nested object we should not use unique validation in serializer instead we shoold set the unique validation in views.py after `serializer.is_valid()` and beore `serializer.save()` and all the code can be somting like this in views.py:

```
uniqueNameError = {"name":["there is another image with this name."]}
def unique_name(name):
    for image in Image.objects.all():
        if name == image.name:
            return False
    return True

class ImageView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ImageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            if not unique_name(request.data['name']):
                return Response(uniqueNameError, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```